# Asymptotic notation question (logarithms)

Tags: logarithms

I am working through some problems and I have come across one I do not understand. Could someone clarify why

$$2x^3 + 3x^2\log(x) + 7x + 1$$

is  $O(x^3\log(x))$ for $x>0$?

I guess I am missing some sort of knowledge to be able to answer this question :(

Comment: https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/  may help.

Comment: Welcome to Math SX! Well, for me it's $O(x^3)$, not $O(x^3\log x)$.

Comment: I have the problem set in both answered and non-answered version using the answered as feedback when I have gone through a whole exercise. I was thinking the same as you, and also answered so when I was working my way through it, but when I looked to compare, I apparently got it wrong. No idea why :(


Edit: Thank you! :D

Comment: Perhaps the second term ought to have read $3x^3\log (x)$ ?

Comment: @lulu I guess I'll have to assume that is the case. I can't find any logarithm rules that would make it true.

Answer (score 0):

if f(x) = $2x^3 + 3x^2\log(x) + 7x + 1$, f(x) = $x^3$$(2 + \frac{3\log(x)}{x} + \frac{7}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x^3})$. Then if x approaches the infinity, ($\frac{3\log(x)}{x} + \frac{7}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x^3}$) is negligible comparing to $x^3$.

And, if $f(x)$ = $2x^3 + 3x^3\log(x) + 7x + 1$, f(x) = $x^3log(x)$$(\frac{2}{log(x)} + 3 + \frac{7}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x^3})$. Then if x approaches the infinity, ($3+ \frac{7}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x^3}$) is negligible comparing to $x^3log(x)$.